# Как мне правильно с JSON перевести поле цвета в int-значение?

Tags: android

Я получаю поле в таком формате:

`"percent_home_color":"#65ff65"`

Мне нужно поменять цвет фона `view`, но `setBackground` хочет `int`.

**Вопрос:** Есть функция для этого или в ручную писать для перевода в десятичную систему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int color = Color.parseColor(String color);
```

[Ссылка на оф. документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))

П. С, вам надо не из JSON, а из строки, т. к. надо сначала достать строку `"percent_home_color":"#65ff65"` из JSON

Comment: спасибо, то что надо!